# Web Audio API analyser.getByteFrequencyData equivalent in Node.js

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I am working with audio and trying to visualize audio data. I have no issue with doing it in the browser thanks to the Web Audio API. There is `AnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData` on the Web Audio API that returns an array of values that range from 0-255, how can I produce the same values in node.js?

I have loaded an `.mp3` audio file and got the channelData.

```
var load = require('audio-loader')

load(fileName).then(
  function(buf) {
    const channelData = buf.getChannelData(0);
  }
)
```

How can I get the same `AnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData` values from `audioBuffer` and `channelData` in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact equivalent for `getByteFrequencyData()` on Node.js but I think using [Meyda](https://meyda.js.org/) should get you reasonably close.

They have a guide on their homepage which shows the usage with Node.js: https://meyda.js.org/guides/offline-node

You could use the [`PowerSpectrum`](https://meyda.js.org/audio-features#amplitudespectrum) feature extractor to get similar data as with `getByteFrequencyData()`.

```
const Meyda = require('meyda');

Meyda.extract('powerSpectrum', channelData);
```